# viewport : rotation to 360° is ignored, how can I force it?

Tags: 3d-view

In the viewport, when i'm rotating my object to 360°, it does nothing.

I guess Blender considers this is a "null" rotation, well, but I need to animate one full rotation !

When using **eulers** rotation, it is easy to fix this in the Graph Editor. But not when using **quaternions**.

So my question is : is there a way to "force" Blender to really do this rotation directly in the viewport ?

Thanks